# Making a set of changes to a string in Java - best practice approach

Tags: java, string, replace

Looking for the best practice Java approach for the following problem.
I have a (relatively) long string and a set of (non-overlapping) changes to make to it - lets say the changes have the signature:

```
change(int startIndex, int endIndex, String replacement);
```

and an example would be

```
assert doChange("aaa",new Change(1,2,"hello")).equals("aHelloa");
```

My plan is to work backwards (so the changing indexes are avoided) though the string splitting into three peices each time and then stitching in the replacement. But I can imagine this has a much more effective/java-like approach... is there an API call I've missed?

Comment: whoops - was distracted... thanks for pointing out.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Or rather http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Java String is immutable, which makes it unsuitable for extended string-based operations. But there are also the classes [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) and [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which represent a mutable string designed for being manipulated. They even have a native [`replace(start, end, str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29) method which does exactly what you are trying to do.

The main difference between these two classes is that StringBuffer is thread-safe while StringBuilder is not. When you don't have multiple threads accessing the same string, use StringBuilder, because it generally performs faster.

Comment: Note StringBuilder is almost *always* a better choice than StringBuffer - they essentially function the same, except that StringBuffer is synchronized and hence comes with a performance cost... if you're not performing concurrent operations on a StringBuffer from multiple threads then StringBuilder is best